# How to pass an optional argument into a Ruby method?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm working on some Watir-webdriver tests in Ruby and can't seem to get the following code to work. I want to pass an optional `validation` argument into the `log_activity` method.

```
def log_activity (type, *validation)
    #do something
end
```

I pass the following arguments into the method:

```
log_activity("license", 1)
```

I expect `validation == 1` to be true, but it is false:

```
puts validation.empty?
-> false

puts validation
-> 1

if validation == 1
    puts "validation!!!!"
else
    puts "WTF"
end
-> WTF
```

What am I doing wrong?

Forgot to mention, I'm using ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Using `puts` can obscure what’s happening in cases like this, as it “flattens” arrays passed to it. Try replacing it with [`p`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-p) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*validation` is an array that includes the second and all arguments afterwards. Given that it is an array, the results you see make sense. You want to check the first element in the *validation array.

Alternatively, if you will only get one optional argument, you can do:

```
def log_activity (type, validation=nil)
    #do something
end
```

Then `validation` will be whatever you passed in.

Comment: Thanks, there is only one optional argument.  I did not realize that using * would result in an array being passed.

Answer (score 1):

Read "[Method Arguments In Ruby](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/method-arguments-in-ruby/)" and look at "Optional Arguments". I found it pretty handy.

I am pasting the useful content:

> Optional Arguments
>
> If you want to decide at runtime how many – if any – arguments you will supply to a method, Ruby allows you to do so. You need to use a special notation when you define the method, e.g.:

```
def some_method(*p)
end
```

> You can call the above method with any number of arguments (including none), e.g.:

```
some_method
```

> or

```
some_method(25)
```

> or

```
some_method(25,"hello", 45, 67)
```

> All of those will work. If no arguments are supplied, then `p` will be an empty array, otherwise, it will be an array that contains the values of all the arguments that were passed in.

Answer (score 0):

when you use *args as the last argument in Ruby, args is an array.

Unfortunately for you, on Ruby 1.8, array.to_s == array.join("")

Try either

```
if validation == [1]
```

or

```
if validation.first == 1
```